# Do browsers ignore "Accept-Encoding" header?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I have a React app which is fetching data from a server this way:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/records',{
  method:'GET',
  headers:{
      'ACCEPT':'application/json',
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
  }
})
.then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({
                records: data,
            });
        });
```

}

Inspecting network activity (dev tools Chrome/Firefox), I see:

[image]

I can add "Accept-Encoding" to my request header and give it any value or I can remove it from the header altogether. No matter what I do, inspecting the network activity always shows my request header accepting gzip, deflate and br. Is this normal? Is there a way for fetch to tell the server it doesn't want any response encoding?

I tried giving gzip a qvalue of 0 as described [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html), but I still see the same result in the network tab.

```
      headers:{
      'ACCEPT':'application/json',
      'Content-Type':'application/json',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip; q=0'
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Accept-Encoding is [a Forbidden Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name). There is no way for JavaScript to change it.

Since the author of a webpage can’t know what encodings a browser is capable of decoding, it isn’t generally useful to set it anyway.

Comment: But how about this? "When a client can process compressed content, the client must inform the server of its capabilities by sending the Accept-Encoding header with the request." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: What about that? It doesn’t contradict anything I said. It supports the second paragraph of this answer in particular.

Comment: The server uses a custom encoding implementation and returns the response with a ``Content-Encoding: mycustomcompression`` header. The client knows that (because they're  both mine) and submits a request with the ``Accept-Encoding: mycustomcompression`` header. But the accept-encoding header seems to get ignored. All I see when inspecting network traffic is gzip, deflate and br.

Comment: If you have written a custom browser which supports `mycustomcompression`, then it should sent that in the `Accept-Encoding` header without the intervention of client-side JS. If you haven't written a custom browser, then I don't see how you can have added support for additional encodings *at the transport layer* which is what the `Accept-Encoding` header applies to.

Comment: So by saying, _"the client must inform the server of its capabilities by sending the Accept-Encoding header with the request"_, they mean "client" as in the browser itself, not the client/server application, i.e., the react app?

Comment: Yes, the browser is the client.